# Create multidimensional array from data sent via POST

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I hope anybody can give me some hint as I am stuck with a problem of creating an array from data sent via POST. The data is coming from 2 tables (2014|10 & 2014|11; 4 rows & 2 cols each)(simplified) and looks like:

```
  doneby_2014|10|0 : 
  doneby_2014|10|1 : 3
  doneby_2014|10|2 : 1
  doneby_2014|10|3 : 
  doneby_2014|10|4 : 2
  doneby_2014|11|0 : 1
  doneby_2014|11|1 : 
  doneby_2014|11|2 : 
  doneby_2014|11|3 : 5
  doneby_2014|11|4 : 

  hours_2014|10|0 : 
  hours_2014|10|1 : 00:15
  hours_2014|10|2 : 02:30
  hours_2014|10|3 : 
  hours_2014|10|4 : 05:25
  hours_2014|11|0 : 02:30
  hours_2014|11|1 : 
  hours_2014|11|2 : 
  hours_2014|11|3 : 00:25
  hours_2014|11|4 :
```

As you can see the POST variable name is created from: rowName_Year|month|lineNo

What I would like to achieve is to put these data into an array that looks like:

```
Array (
 [doneby] => Array (
  [2014] => Array (
   [10] => Array (
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    )
   [11] => Array (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    )
   )
  )
 [hours] => Array (
  [2014] => Array (
   [10] => Array (
    [0] => 00:15
    [1] => 02:30
    [2] => 05:25
    )
   [11] => Array (
    [0] => 02:30
    [1] => 00:25
    )
   )
  )
 )
```

What would be the best approach to tackle this problem? Can anybody help?
Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: `<input name="doneby[2014][10][]" ... />`

Comment: Agree with @u_mulder , change name of your input "why make it simple when we can make it complicated" (french proverb not sure use worldwide)

Comment: How is the data being sent? Is someone filling out a form or are you getting a text string POSTed automatically from somewhere?

Comment: In Germany we have the same saying - additionally - in my case - "with all those trees I couldn't find the forrest"...
The trick/suggestion from u_mulder saved my day!!!